# Reduce ImageView Size from a Button Click

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have created an `ImageView` and `Button` and would like to reduce the `imageView` size once the `button` has been clicked or pressed and set the `ImageView` back to default.

Is this possible and if so how would I be able to achieve this and set the 
`LayoutParams.width = 168dp`?

**ImageView Code:**

```
<ImageView
 android:layout_width="168dp"
 android:layout_height="30dp"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:id="@+id/imgCircle"
 android:background="@drawable/ic_img_circle"
 android:clickable="false"/>
```

**Button Code:**

```
<Button
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/btnSmall"
 android:text="Small"
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
 android:background="@mipmap/ic_bg_button"
 android:textStyle="bold"
 android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>
```

Attempted Code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if ( v == NEXT ) {
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = TEST.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = 168; //Need this to be 168dp
        layoutParams.height = 30; //Need this to be 30dp
        TEST.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        TEST.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_bg_button);
        Random r = new Random();
         random = r.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1;
        if(random == 1) {
            textQueston.setText("Spin the Circle Clockwise");
        }
        else if(random == 2) {
            textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Blue");
        }
        else if(random == 3) {
            textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Red");
        }
        else if(random == 4) {
            textQueston.setText("Spin the Circle Anti-Clockwise");
        }
        else if(random == 5) {
            textQueston.setText("Make Circle Smaller");
        }
        else if(random == 6) {
            textQueston.setText("Make Circle Larger");
        }
    }
    if ( v == BLUE ) {
        if (random == 2 ) {
            TEST.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }
    else if ( v == RED ) {
        if (random == 3) {
            TEST.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
    else if ( v == CLOCKWISE ) {
        if (random == 1) {
            Animation aniRotateClk = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.button_rotate_clockwise);
            TEST.startAnimation(aniRotateClk);

            /* start Animation */
            //TEST.startAnimation(rotation);
        }
    }
    else if (v == ANTICLOCKWISE) {
        if (random == 4) {
            Animation animRotateAclk = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.button_rotate_anticlockwise);
            TEST.startAnimation(animRotateAclk);
        }
    }
    else if( v == SMALL) {
        if (random == 5) {
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = TEST.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = 150; //Need this to be 150dp
            layoutParams.height = 20; //Need this to be 20dp
            TEST.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }
    else if ( v == LARGE) {
        if ( random == 6) {
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = TEST.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = 200; //Need this to be 200dp
            layoutParams.height = 50; //Need this to be 50dp
            TEST.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should setOnClickListener for the button and then each click you set LayoutParams for imageView.

Search keyword "setLayoutParams for imageView"

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to change your `height` and `width` of `ImageView` by `Button` tap/click:

You can increase/decrease height  & width by `getLayoutParams().height` & `getLayoutParams().width`

```
 btnSmall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            imgCircle.getLayoutParams().height = 500;
            imgCircle.getLayoutParams().width = 500;
            imgCircle.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
    });
```

Change your Code According to my Code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if ( v == NEXT ) {
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = TEST.getLayoutParams();

    TEST.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    TEST.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_bg_button);
    layoutParams.width = 168; //Need this to be 168dp
    layoutParams.height = 30; //Need this to be 30dp

    Random r = new Random();
    random = r.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1;
    if(random == 1) {
        textQueston.setText("Spin the Circle Clockwise");
    }
    else if(random == 2) {
        textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Blue");
    }
    else if(random == 3) {
        textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Red");
    }
    else if(random == 4) {
        textQueston.setText("Spin the Circle Anti-Clockwise");
    }
    else if(random == 5) {
        textQueston.setText("Make Circle Smaller");
    }
    else if(random == 6) {
        textQueston.setText("Make Circle Larger");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.dl_image);
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 120;
```